# returning JSON response from AWS Glue Pythonshell job to the boto3 caller

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is there a way to send a JSON response (of a dictionary of outputs) from A AWS Glue pythonshell job? Similar to returning a JSON response from AWS Lambda?

I am calling a Glue pythonshell job like below:

```
response = glue.start_job_run(
               JobName = 'test_metrics',
               Arguments = {
                 '--test_metrics': 'test_metrics',
                 '--s3_target_path_key':   's3://my_target',
                 '--s3_target_path_value':   's3://my_target_value'} )

print(response)
```

The response I get is a `200` stating the fact that the Glue `start_job_run` was a success. From the documentation, all I see is the result if a Glue job is either written in `s3` or some other `database`.

I tried adding `return {'result':'some_string'}` at the end of my Glue pythonshell job to test if it works or not with below code.

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv,
                          ['JOB_NAME',
                           's3_target_path_key',
                           's3_target_path_value'])
print ("Target path key is: ", args['s3_target_path_key'])
print ("Target Path value is: ", args['s3_target_path_value'])
return {'result':"some_string"}
```

But it throws error `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`

Comment: from glue python, call boto3 and send response body to SNS and trigger lambda by SNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glue is not made to return response as it is expected to run long running operation inside it. Blocking for response for long running task is not right approach in itself. Instead of it, you may use `launch job (service 1) -> execute job  (service 2)-> get result  (service 3)` pattern. You can send json response to AWS service 3 which you want to launch from AWS Service 2 (execute job) e.g. if you launch lambda from glue job, you can send json response to it.